# Linq to SQL: WHERE IN statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
CREATE TABLE [MyNames]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [MyNames] VALUES ('John')
INSERT INTO [MyNames] VALUES ('Jane')
INSERT INTO [MyNames] VALUES ('Peter')
INSERT INTO [MyNames] VALUES ('Montgomery')
INSERT INTO [MyNames] VALUES ('Sarah')
```

Based on the above (hypothetical) SQL schema and data, I want to use Linq to SQL to get all results where the name is **in** values of an array.

```
string[] names = {"John", "Cassandra", "Sarah"};

var results = (from n in db.Names
               where n.Name **in names**
               select n).ToList();
```

The results should include `John` and `Sarah`. With that information I am then able to add the entries that need to be added, in this case `Cassandra`.

I don't want to load all the Names because the list can get exceptionally long.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `names.Contains()`:

```
string[] names = {"John", "Cassandra", "Sarah"};

var results = (from n in db.Names
               where names.Contains(n.Name)
               select n).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Such an obvious answer. I can't believe I never thought of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Contains` extension method:

```
var results = (from n in db.Names
               where names.Contains(n.Name)
               select n).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = (from n in db.Names
               where names.Any(x=>x == n.Name)
               select n).ToList();
```